# How to get an RSS feed automatically sent to Kindle?

Tags: rss, kindle

I would like to get one of my favourite blogs to be sent to my Kindle. I wonder if there is any such solution. Do you know any website, service or app that could do it for me?

Comment: Have you tried [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/)?

Comment: It could only send articles one by one, thats not that good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found three of them using DuckDuckGo, although I've no idea if any of them meet your requirements:

http://kindlefeeder.com/

http://www.kindlesend.com/

http://kindle4rss.com/